# input radio - не передаёт значение в БД

Tags: php, html

Выкладываю код. Почему-то радио кнопки не передают значения в БД. Подскажите, в чём проблема.

```
if (empty($_POST))
{
?>

    <form action="invite.php" method="post">

<b>Электронная почта&nbsp;</b><br />
</div>

<input type="text" name="login"  /></div>
<b>Пароль</b></div>

<input type="password" name="password"  />
            </div>

 Еда <input type="radio" value="j" name="food">  <input type="radio" value="d" name="food">
 </div>

 Не еда <input type="radio" name="nofoot" value="2">
 </div>

<input type="submit" value="Готово" >
</div>
    </form>

    <?php
}
else
{

    $login = (isset($_POST['login'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']) : '';
    $password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) : '';
    $nofood = (isset($_POST['nofood'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nofood']) : '';
    $food = (isset($_POST['food'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['food']) : '';

    $error = false;
    $errort = '';

    if (strlen($login) < 2)
    {
        $error = true;
        $errort .= 'Вы не указали ваш e-mail';
    }
    if (strlen($password) < 6)
    {
        $error = true;
        $errort .= 'Пароль должен быть не меннее 6 символов';
    }

    $query = "SELECT `id`
                FROM `users`
                WHERE `login`='{$login}'
                LIMIT 1";
    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql)==1)
    {
        $error = true;
        $errort .= 'В базе уже есть эта почта.Укажите другую.';
    }

    if (!$error)
    {

        $salt = GenerateSalt();
        $hashed_password = md5(md5($password) . $salt);

        $query = "INSERT
                    INTO `users`
                    SET
                        `login`='{$login}',
                        `city`='{$city}',
                        `password`='{$hashed_password}',
                        `salt`='{$salt}'";
        $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        print '<h4>Поздравляем, Вы успешно зарегистрированы!</h4><a href="login.php">Авторизоваться</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        print '<h4>Возникли следующие ошибки</h4>' . $errort;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать одинаковые имена у кнопок, но только с разными значениями

```
Еда:<input type="radio" value="yfood" name="food">
Не еда:<input type="radio" value="nfood" name="food">
....
$food = (isset($_POST['food']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['food']) : "";
...
mysql_insert("INSERT INTO `users` SET `food` = '".$food."' ");
```

Да и вообще, я не заметил в вашем коде, чтобы передавались данные из $food в БД